# SQLite Insert not working for large number of records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to insert about 30,000 records into an SQLite database. The insert statement doesn't insert any of the records - however if I break it into chunks of say 200 records at a time it seems to work fine. It doesn't throw an exception - it just doesn't actually seem to insert the record. There must be something dead simple that I am missing...

```
app.applyChangesPriceBands = function(pbresultset, callback) {

    app.db.transaction(
        function(tx) {
            var l = pbresultset.length;
            var sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO priceBands (prb_ID, stk_ItemNo, prb_Priceband, prb_CurrentPrice, prb_NormalPrice, prb_Deleted, prb_DateLastUpdated) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            var e;

            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                e = pbresultset[i];

                var params = [e.prb_ID, e.stk_ItemNo, e.prb_Priceband, e.prb_CurrentPrice, e.prb_NormalPrice, e.prb_Deleted, e.prb_DateLastUpdated];
                tx.executeSql(sql, params);
            }

        }
    );

    app.finishedUpdating(app.updateType);

}
```

Comment: I'm not particularly "up" on sqlite, however I would guess your issue is to do with buffers or caches - 30k rows is a lot to do in one action, particularly as you are performing the action as a transaction - i.e. roll backable (higher overhead).

Comment: Is your database using rollback journal or write-ahead log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to commit every 100th insert. Maybe it's because of large rollback segment.

Comment: This worked a treat so I guess it was due to trying to insert too many transactions in one go!